# Restoring SilverStripe's .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, silverstripe

I'm having some trouble fixing up an issue on my client's SilverStripe site.

What happened was that another developer in my team had overwritten the .htaccess file without making a backup of the file to show an under construction page. The client has since wanted to restore their site back to working order; but we have no idea what that original .htaccess file looks like. I have tried a couple of different .htaccess examples on the net but none of them have worked for me. I am receiving the following error:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method Versioned::extraStatics() should not be called statically in /home/wwwcont/public_html/sapphire/core/model/DataObjectDecorator.php on line 69
```

Unfortunately there are no backups of the site as no one was doing them. I also have zero server experience. I can post an example of the .htaccess file if necessary. Do I re-install SilverStripe?

*Edit In terms of the current folder structure, it seems that "framework" is named "sapphire" - which from what I understand is an MVC. Could this perhaps be related?

So I pulled down the database and got the website running locally - must be a server issue then. I do however find it strange as I did not make any changes to the server.

Comment: The error you're getting doesn't look related to the .htaccess at all. That's a strict error which should not stop your site working in live mode.

Comment: Thanks @DanHensby; the strange thing is that the site was working before, and the only thing that changed was the .htaccess folder.

Comment: If you're seeing that error on the live site, then you have your server/site misconfigured - it's running in dev mode and/or has display_errors on.

Comment: The folder should be called sapphire in 2.x - it was changed to framework in 3.x

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the version of silverstripe you should be able to grab it from the appropriate release of https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer

It appears the site is 2.x so you'll likely want this one: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer/blob/post-2.4/.htaccess